# why my pytorch image classification sampler spit out the strange length value?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I'm training the Image classification 
I made the train and valid cross-validation sets

```
EPOCHS = 5
SAVE_DIR = 'models'
MODEL_SAVE_PATH = os.path.join(SAVE_DIR, 'please.pt')
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
best_valid_loss = float('inf')

if not os.path.isdir(f'{SAVE_DIR}'):
    os.makedirs(f'{SAVE_DIR}')
print("start")
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    print('================================',epoch ,'================================')
    for i , (train_idx, valid_idx) in enumerate(zip(train_indexes, valid_indexes)):
        print(i,train_idx,valid_idx,len(train_idx),len(valid_idx))

        trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler= SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx))
        valloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=SubsetRandomSampler(valid_idx))

        print(len(trainloader.dataset),len(valloader.dataset))

        train_loss, train_acc ,model= train(model, device, trainloader, optimizer, criterion)
        valid_loss, valid_acc,model = evaluate(model, device, valloader, criterion)

        if valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
            best_valid_loss = valid_loss
            torch.save(model,MODEL_SAVE_PATH)

        print(f'| Epoch: {epoch+1:02} | Train Loss: {train_loss:.3f} | Train Acc: {train_acc*100:05.2f}% | Val. Loss: {valid_loss:.3f} | Val. Acc: {valid_acc*100:05.2f}% |')
```

> start
>   ================================ 0 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402
>   18403 18404] 18827 2690  
> 21517 21517

but the output of sampling is very strange 
the output of

> len(train_idx) and len(valid_idx) = 18827 2690

this is correct 

But. when I print the

> print(len(trainloader.dataset),len(valloader.dataset)) = 21517 , 21517

is something wrong with sampler???

Answer (score 0):

`DataLoader.dataset` is just a reference to the dataset used when defining the dataloader. Since both dataloaders use the same dataset the result you see is expected as it doesn't take the dataloader's sampler into account.

If you want to know the size of your dataset after taking into account the samplers then use

```
len(trainloader.sampler)
len(valloader.sampler)
```